# Why is Granger test implication different from significances of coefficients?

Tags: statistical-significance, regression-coefficients, vector-autoregression, granger-causality

I am running a simple Granger causality test on a VAR(4) model. I obtain the following coefficients for it

```
Di = Di.l1 + Dc.l1 + Di.l2 + Dc.l2 + Di.l3 + Dc.l3 + Di.l4 + Dc.l4 + const 

        Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)   
Di.l1 -0.0329008  0.0909051  -0.362  0.71796   
Dc.l1  0.5837770  0.2205362   2.647  0.00906 **
Di.l2  0.1883112  0.0886601   2.124  0.03546 * 
Dc.l2  0.0380220  0.2163601   0.176  0.86076   
Di.l3  0.1363833  0.0901364   1.513  0.13255   
Dc.l3 -0.0123208  0.2107619  -0.058  0.95347   
Di.l4  0.2173102  0.0849079   2.559  0.01156 * 
Dc.l4 -0.2605697  0.2134410  -1.221  0.22424   
const  0.0005628  0.0021497   0.262  0.79388
```

Clearly the first lag of the Dc is significant here. Which, from my understanding, would mean Dc Granger causes Di.

However, when I run `causality(VAR-model-of-interest, cause="Dc")` I obtain the following.

```r
    Granger causality H0: Dc do not Granger-cause Di

data:  VAR object VAR4
F-Test = 1.9381, df1 = 4, df2 = 276, p-value = 0.1043
```

Which means that I assume that there is NO Granger causality.

Should I trust the test over the significances of the coefficients and if yes, why?

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You have a situation where multiple coefficients are jointly not statistically significantly different from zero while one of them is individually statistically significantly different from zero. Thus you cannot reject $H_{0A}\colon \beta_1=\beta_2=\beta_3=\beta_4=0$ even though you can reject $H_{0B}\colon \beta_1=0$ at a chosen significance level (say, 5%). Of course, it is impossible that $H_{0A}$ holds while $H_{0B}$ does not. However, at the level of precision that you are able to achieve, you get seemingly conflicting results. This is due to estimation imprecision and can happen much more generally than just in testing for Granger causality. The question is likely covered in your favourite introductory econometrics textbook.

One way out is to decide upfront which of the two hypotheses you are going to test and to stick to it. I suppose in your case it is $H_{0A}$.

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer! Very helpful!

Comment: @Silke, you are welcome!

Comment: @Silke, what do you think about my answer? If it is helpful and clear, you may accept it by clicking on the tick mark to the left. Otherwise, you may ask for further clarification. This is [how Cross Validated works](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tour).